# Delete image from Folder/Database using RowCommand/RowDeleting events

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am uploading images and display them in a `Gridview`.I save the images in a folder and the name in the database.Now I want if I uploaded 3 pictures and have to delete one which I select.So I have picture 1 2 3. When I select picture 2 than this will be deleted..How can I do that? This is my code to upload my pictures:

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileuploadimages.PostedFile.FileName);
fileuploadimages.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Images/" + filename));

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["baza_chestionar"].ToString());
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Images(ImageName,ImagePath) values(@ImageName,@ImagePath)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageName", filename);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImagePath", "Images/" + filename);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
Response.Redirect("~/upload.aspx");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below GridView's events to delete the images..

> 1. RowCommand
> 2. RowDeleting

---

### Code Behind

```
protected void grd_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    grd.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Control of the file Name"); 
    //Find control that contains file Name
    if (System.IO.File.Exists("FilePath"))
    {
        File.Delete(Path.Combine("path", "FileName"));
    }
    //Your Delete Code to delete record from database
}

protected void grd_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    grd.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Control of the file Name"); 
    //Find control that contains file Name
    if (System.IO.File.Exists("FilePath"))
    {
        File.Delete(Path.Combine("path", "FileName"));
    }
    //Your Delete Code to delete record from database
}
```

---

### HTML

```
<asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" onrowcommand="grd_RowCommand" 
onrowdeleting="grd_RowDeleting">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="delete" runat="server" Text="Select" CommandName="delete"></asp:LinkButton> 
                <asp:LinkButton ID="deleteRow" runat="server" Text="Select" CommandName="deleteRow"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

---

Please note that - you can use either `RowCommand/RowDeleting` Events...and I will go with `RowDeleting`

Answer (score 2):

To delete a file use `System.IO.File.Delete`:

```
File.Delete(Path.Combine(path, filename));
```

The rest of the implementation details, how you notify the server of the appropriate file to delete, is up to you.